# master theorem with 2 parameters, neither n

Tags: algorithm

Im doing a course of Algorithms design and I have a homework to calculate the cost of a function, I do some research and discover about the master theorem, but all the examples I see are about *n* and in this function I have 2 parameters but neither are n.

```
function estudia(i,j){
    if i = j then resulta(i,j);
    M = (i+j)/2;
    C = (j-i)/4;
    estudia(i,M);
    estudia(i+C,M+C);
    combina(i,j);
}

function combina(i,j){
    ancho = j-i-1;
    p = 1;
    while p * p < ancho loop
        p = p+1;
        resulta(p,j);
}
```

We know that resulta(x,y) is O(1), but how I can calculate the cost of a recursive function with the master theorem having 2 parameters i and j instead of n? Is not possible and I have to use the substitution method?

Comment: You can compute combina first. Then use that result to find estudia.

Comment: No matter the methods to use, you need to write down the recursion equation first.

Comment: Yes, I did combina using summatories and it gives me 2*sqrt( (j-i+1)+2 ) but I still have the problem of having it without n, and I search in a couple books(CLRS and dasgupta) about it, but only explains the basic cases with parameter being n

Comment: where do call estudia ? What is the value for i and j in that call ?

Comment: also what do i and j mean ? Usually, n mean the size of input.

Comment: It doesnt say, I supposed i and j are 2 numbers but the heading of the exercise only says "Analyze the next algorithm, knowing that the function resulta(x,y) is 0(1)"

Comment: Ok. With that setting, you can safely assume that i and j are fix parameters. Thus, you can secretly change i to n, and j to m. And analyze the code with n and m parameters. After you solve it out in the draft paper, rewrite it with i and j.

Comment: Actually, it could be easier. I will write a solution.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42046324/781723, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/69854/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @set92 Please give feedback to my answer. Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your settings, we assume that i and j are fixed parameters. Let `n = j - i`, the distance.

For `estudia(i,M)`, the distance `M-i=n/2`, for `estudia(i+C,M+C)`, the distance is still `n/2`. `combina(i,j)=combina(n)`.

Let `T(n)` = cost of estudia. You can construct recursion formula for `estudia` as:

`T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + combina(n)`.

As you said, you can solve `combina(n)` (I will not solve it because it is still your assignment). Plug in result for `combina(n)`, you get master theorem.